# Using a progress bar in Visual Basic while running a batch script in background

Tags: vb.net

I've got a simple Visual Basic Program that I've put together that calls some batch scripts that causes them to be hidden while it copies files and now I'd like to use a progress bar to give the user a visual because I've hidden the cmd window. Thanks in advance for the help! Here is the code:

```
Public Class Choices
    Private Sub Choices_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDocuments_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDocuments.Click
        Dim wsh
        wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        wsh.Run("C:\Batch\myDocs.Bat", 0, True)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDesktop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDesktop.Click
        Dim wsh
        wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        wsh.Run("C:\Batch\desk.Bat", 0, True)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnFavorites_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFavorites.Click
        Dim wsh
        wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        wsh.Run("C:\Batch\favs.Bat", 0, True)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAll.Click
        Dim wsh
        wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        wsh.Run("C:\Batch\all.Bat", 0, True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are using older VB code, you have it tagged as VB.NET, and I'm answering accordingly.

You need need to execute your batch files in a way that you can get the output of the batch files to then show to your user.  You can do this by executing the batch files [using an instance of the `Process` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process.aspx), and redirecting the output.  To do this in an asynchronous fashion, you would attach the event handlers for `OutputDataReceived` and `ErrorDataReceived` and calling `BeginOutputReadLine` and `BeginErrorReadLine`.

To get you started, I'm providing a small sample code for the case of Documents:

```
Private Sub btnDocuments_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDocuments.Click
    DoWork("C:\Batch\myDocs.Bat")
End Sub

Sub DoWork(ByVal batFileName As String)
    Using p As New Process()
        p.StartInfo.FileName = batFileName
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        AddHandler p.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf BatFileProcess_OutputDataReceived
        AddHandler p.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf BatFileProcess_ErrorDataReceived
        p.Start()
        p.BeginOutputReadLine()
        p.BeginErrorReadLine()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub BatFileProcess_OutputDataReceived(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    Me.Invoke(Sub()
                  ' Perform UI update here for normal output.
              End Sub)
End Sub

Private Sub BatFileProcess_ErrorDataReceived(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    Me.Invoke(Sub()
                  ' Perform UI update here for error output.
              End Sub)
End Sub
```

Note that this update will be from a thread separate from the UI thread, thus the need to use `Invoke` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I know I marked it as vb.net because I've used vb.net to build all the screens in Visual Studio but I've used a bit of VB script to run my batch files. Thanks for the help!

Comment: But if you look at the code above I have a Private Sub that handles the button click, and that's what initiates my code in the sub.

Comment: @jfritts6524 Glad I could help. My answer does not provide a progress bar, as I'm not sure how you'd report progress from the batch files, unless it were just like a "N of M files completed" deal.

Comment: @jfritts6524 Right, the button click handler would be calling the `DoWork` for its particular batch file in the case of my example.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm being a pest but I guess I'm just still confused because to the best of my knowledge i can't create a sub within a sub. So how would I make the DoWork portion be inside my button click sub? And again you don't have to give me the exact answer but atleast a nudge in the right direction would be very helpful, I'm a novice at scripting and programming and I using this to learn.

Comment: @jfritts6524 `DoWork` would be declared just once within your class `Choices`.  Then your event handlers would call `DoWork` with the corresponding batch file.  For example, the body of `btnDocuments_Click` would simply be `DoWork("C:\Batch\myDocs.Bat")`.

Comment: So basically I'm just creating a sub under the Class called DoWork and then calling that sub within the btnDocuments_Click sub?

Comment: @jfritts6524 Correct. `DoWork` handles starting up the batch file and attaching the listeners for the output from those files.  Then `btnDocuments_Click`, `btnDesktop_Click`, `btnFavorites_Click`, and `btnAll_Click` simply call `DoWork` on the corresponding file.  There's still a fair amount of work to do, depending on what you want to show the end-user as the batch files run, but this should get you well started.

Comment: I've edited my code to reflect what I think you've said could you check my original code that I edited and tell me if that looks right?

Comment: Well I've worked it further to where now I have no visible errors but now I'm getting a pop up error saying that it can find the file specified.

Comment: @jfritts6524 You shouldn't really be updating your question as you code, as it invalidates your question as originally asked. Also, I notice from your update that you are getting hung up on some pretty basics of coding -- how to create and use basic methods.  There's really too much to walk you through in this format, as you don't have reputation level required for Chat, so I'm putting together a sample solution more specific to your case.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I'm still really new to the forum and I'm a novice coder. Sorry if I've been a pain. I appreciate all the help though.

Comment: [This project](http://www.filedropper.com/so23117452example) should have everything you need to get going.  You are really close, now, except you don't need `Sub Main` and you will need to provide the full file path to the batch files (ex: `DoWork("C:\Batch\myDocs.Bat")`).

Comment: I hate to bother you once again. But the code works great except for now the batch file doesn't carry out the xcopy commands that I've written. I added in some stuff to echo similar to what you put in your bat file. But the actual commands in between won't execute it just skips over them and goes to the echo after the xcopy commands.

Comment: @jfritts6524 Did you add the `@echo off` to the top of the .bat? Did you verify that the files were not actually being copied? It may have something to do with working directories.  Did the xcopy work correctly in your original calls?

Comment: Yes it worked fine in the original calls. I've made sure that I put the _@echo off at the top. The code in the batch script is really simple. It's just:

'code' @echo off
echo .jpg\ > exclusion.txt
echo .wmv\ >> exclusion.txt
echo .bmp\ >> exclusion.txt

xcopy "C:\Users\%username%\Documents" "h:\%username% My Documents" /D /E /R /H /I /K /Y EXCLUDE:exclusion.txt 'code'

Comment: @jfritts6524 After some searching on the Internet, it seems for `xcopy` that if you redirect output, you must redirect input as well.  Simply add `p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True` to the `DoWork` method.

Comment: @jfritts6524 To mark the code block use the `, generally to the left of the 1 on the keyboard.

Comment: Sweet! That works! You've been a tremendous help! If there is anything I can do as far a giving you a thumbs up or something to help your rep points let me know because you've been a major help! Thanks!

Comment: @jfritts6524 There is the vote option to the left of the answer at top.  But, ultimately, if you felt this answer solves your question, you could accept it as such (there will be an outline of a checkmark that will turn green when you click it), so that if anyone else has a similar problem in the future, they can find your question and see that it has been answered.